# Merge two columns of data table on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to solve the following problem with R:

I have a **data table** with values from two labs: `lab1` and `lab2`. It could be that `lab1` or `lab2` contains `NA` values so then the column "lab3" should contain the non-NA value. If `lab1` and `lab2` contain `NA`s of course `lab3` is also `NA`, but if `lab1` and `lab2` contain values, `lab3` should apply the value of lab2 (this is the "more important" lab).

Example:

```
lab1     lab2     lab3
5        7        7       < lab 3 contains the value of lab 2 (because more important)
8        10       10      < lab 3 contains the value of lab 2 (because more important)
NA       3        3       < lab 3 contains the value of lab 2, because lab 1 is NA
9        NA       9       < lab 3 contains the value of lab 1, because lab 2 is NA
NA       NA       NA      < lab 3 contains NA, because lab 1 and lab 2 contain NA
```

I found the function coalesce (`dplyr`) but I was not able to define the primary importance of `lab2` (over `lab1`).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "primary importance" is set by the order of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `fcoalesce` if you are working with `data.table`

```
> setDT(df)[, lab3 := fcoalesce(lab2, lab1)][]
   lab1 lab2 lab3
1:    5    7    7
2:    8   10   10
3:   NA    3    3
4:    9   NA    9
5:   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
df %>%
  mutate(lab3 = ifelse(!is.na(lab2), lab2, lab1))

   lab1  lab2  lab3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     7     7
2     8    10    10
3    NA     3     3
4     9    NA     9
5    NA    NA    NA
```